# Possible to run Stored Procedure using documentDB SDK for Python?

Tags: python, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Tornado and pydocumentDB to run a storage application on Azure. I also have a stored procedure:

```
function userIDSproc() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id='user_ids_counter'",
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
            // else take 1st element from feed
            if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
            else tryUpdate(feed[0])
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');

    function tryUpdate(document){
        document.counter += 1;
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(document['counter']);
        var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(document._self, document, function (err, document, options) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // If we have successfully updated the document - return it in the response body.
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(document);            
        });
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is increase the `counter` property of my user_ids document every time a new user is generated and their document is added to the collection. Is it possible to call that Sproc, update the counter, then query the document for the new counter, then use that new counter as the ID for the new user? The documentDB SDK on GitHub shows a couple methods like `QueryStoredProcedures(self, collection_link, query, options=None):`
 and `ReadStoredProcedures(self, collection_link, options=None):` but nothing to actually execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the DocumentDB Python SDK, you can call `ExecuteStoredProcedure(self, sproc_link, params, options=None)`.

You can find a short example in the SDK's unit tests here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/e605e7ca7b1ddd2454f1014f536a0fded9e6f234/test/crud_tests.py#L3408-L3409

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! document_client is pretty huge, I didn't see those other methods tucked away on the bottom there.